# joomla in Google appengine

Tags: migration, joomla, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I was wondering if I can transfer my existing site based on joomla! in Google appengine. How can I do that?

Will it be easy if I start from scratch (modifying joomla! for Google appengine).

Please advise me tutorials, walkthrough and your suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla is written using PHP.

By default Google App Engine only supports applications written in Python, and in the future Java. See [Google App Engine FAQ](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#language) so PHP is not natively supported.

---

There is a way to run PHP on Google App Engine however by using a Java Virtual Machine named [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/). Your biggest issue will be that it will require large amounts of modification to Joomla's source code with the change to using GQL instead of SQL.

Source: http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/92-Running-PHP-on-Google-App-Engine.html

---

Are you looking for ways to easily scale your Joomla installation?

Comment: I understand. Ya, now I can see Google appengine only supports python and now java (early access). No, I guess django will be much easier and better to migrate to rather than converting joomla! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am trying hard to learn about how to create [Joomla Templates](http://www.templatemagician.com/category/Joomla-templates). So, as a beginner I do not have much to say but I think the Following link might help you in the right way.

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347?step=347